# Shouldn't dereferencing a pointer provide the value inside the address that you are referencing to?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

my code here basically involves a pointer to a 1-D array of 3 integers, I just don't get the output for the line of code 'printf ("Value at address B[0] is: %d\n",*B);'. Like shouldn't dereferencing pointer B provide me the value to the address that it is referencing to? Is there something wrong with my statement? Thanks, the output didn't give me the value instead it provided me the address :'))

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (void){
    int B[2][3] = {{2,3,4},{5,6,7}};
    int (*p)[3] = B;
    printf("Address at B[0] is: %d or %d\n", B, &B[0]);
    printf ("Value at address B[0] is: %d\n",*B); /*when I dereference pointer B here, shouldn't it give me 
    the value, why is it that when I execute the code, it gives still gives me the address?*/
    printf("B + 1 = %d\n", B+1);
}
```

[image: Output from the above code]

Answer (score 1):

`B` is not a pointer. `B` is an array of two arrays of three `int`.

When an array is used in an expression, other than as the operand of size of or unary `&` or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

In `printf ("Value at address B[0] is: %d\n",*B);`, `B` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So the result of that conversion is `&B[0]`. Then `*` dereferences that address. Since `&B[0]` is the address of `B[0]`, `*&B[0]` is `B[0]`.

Since `B` is an array of two arrays of three `int`, `B[0]` is an array of three `int`. Since it is an array used in an expression, and is not the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` and is not a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. The result of that conversion is `&B[0][0]`. That is the same address as `&B[0]` but has a different type.

Then `printf ("Value at address B[0] is: %d\n",*B);` attempts to print this address. However, `%d` is for converting `int` values to decimal numerals, whereas `*B` produces a pointer, not an `int`. The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard. Sometimes it will print the address or part of it.

To print addresses, convert them to `void *` and print them using `%p`:

```
printf("Address at B[0] is: %p or %p\n", (void *) B, (void *) &B[0]);
printf ("Value at address B[0] is: %p\n", (void *) *B);
printf("B + 1 = %p\n", (void *) (B+1));
```

If you print `**B`, that will show the value of the first element:

- In `**B`, `B` will be converted to a pointer to its first element, `&B[0]`, yielding `**&B[0]`.
- Then `*&B[0]` reduces to `B[0]`, yielding `*B[0]`.
- Then `B[0]` is converted to a pointer to its first element, `&B[0][0]`, yielding `*&B[0][0]`.
- Then that reduces to `B[0][0]`.

Comment: In your statement here, "The result of that conversion is &B[0][0]. That is the same address as &B[0] but has a different type." What do you mean by them having a different type?? Thank you so much btw I understand now the thing on why *B prints the address of its first element.

Comment: @Dumplings: `&B[0]` is the address of an array of three `char`, so its type is “pointer to array of three `char`”. `&B[0][0]` is the address of a `char`, so its type is “pointer to `char`.